# How can I employ the "use" declaration within a matching pattern?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, idisposable

The situation: A function returns an Option(Stream). In the calling function I have to unwrap it in a way so that the stream is disposed after use. Where should I put the "use" declaration?

```
let getSteamOpt = if System.Random().NextDouble() > 0.5 then Some(new MemoryStream()) else None
let createAndUseStreamIfAny = 
    let streamOpt = getSteamOpt
    match streamOpt with
    | Some( (* use <-- doesn't work like this *) stream) -> printf "stream has to be disposed after this"
    | None -> printf "blah"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let createAndUseStreamIfAny = 
    let streamOpt = getSteamOpt
    match streamOpt with
    | Some(s) -> 
        use stream = s
        printf "stream has to be disposed after this"
    | None -> printf "blah"
```

Comment: To elaborate, you can't put a `use` inside the pattern itself -- you need to put it inside the handler for the pattern. Personally, I would write `use s = s` instead, because that ensures you don't accidentally use the value from the pattern instead of the value bound with `use` -- i.e., so you don't try to use the value after it's disposed by the `use`.